# Can't load assembly I'm executing in

Tags: .net, system.reflection

I have a case where 2 C# projects need to reference each other. So assembly A references assembly B. And assembly B uses reflection to load A. Works great in a command line application.

But in My Word COM AddIn I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WindwardReports, Version=15.0.142.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=34ffe15f4bbb8e53' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.

FusionLog

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = WindwardReports, Version=15.0.142.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34ffe15f4bbb8e53 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\config\\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports/WindwardReports.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports/WindwardReports.EXE.
```

This same code works fine in a command line app.

The code:
Here is the code. (The syntax is a little weird because this is Java code that is turned to .NET using IKVM, but it is .NET code when it is running).

```
    cli.System.Reflection.Assembly assm;
    int indexSemi = outputBuilder.indexOf(';');
    if (indexSemi != -1) {
        String dllFilename = outputBuilder.substring (0, indexSemi);
        outputBuilder = outputBuilder.substring(indexSemi + 1);
        assm = cli.System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dllFilename);
    }
    else
        assm = cli.System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    cli.System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle hdl = cli.System.Activator.CreateInstance(assm.get_FullName(), outputBuilder);
    return (IOutputBuilderEngine) hdl.Unwrap();
```

The System.Activator.CreateInstance() is what's throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: @Aruna - Sorry, I should have done that at the start. Up there now.

Comment: How are your assemblies (both A and B) deployed - as in, where in the filesystem are they supposed to reside? Are you passing a full path to the LoadFile method?

Comment: May I know, Does your code go into the `if` block or `else` block?

Comment: @DavidThielen, Also please advise what is the value of `outputBuilder`?

Comment: @Aruna - the code goes into the if block. outputBuilder is "full_path_to_dll;full_class_name"

Answer (score 0):

The code is trying to load the DLL from a file.

As you can see from the fusion log, it's looking for your DLL in four places, then giving up:

1. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports.DLL
2. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports/WindwardReports.DLL
3. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports.EXE
4. C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Root/Office16/WindwardReports/WindwardReports.EXE

Seems like your DLL is located somewhere else. If you do actually need to load it from disk, you'll need the correct path. Though if it is the executing assembly, why can' you just use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`?

Comment: I'm running in WindwardReports.dll trying to load OfficeOutputBuilder.dll. But why is it searching for the DLL that I'm running in?

Comment: You don't show enough code to know. Investigate the value of `outputBuilder`. It seems to contain the wrong DLL name.